# Android layout_weight is not working as expected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

Layout weight doesn't seem to be working in this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Header -->

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
        layout="@layout/header" />

    <!-- Layout -->

    <ScrollView
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/light_blue"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/home_first_layout"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <!-- <ImageView
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/upcoming" /> -->
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The home_first_layout contains three horizontal layouts. They have been assigned layout weights. Can you guys explain why the layout weight doesn't show the expected results?

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Obviously. The weighted dimension must be **0dp**.

Comment: oh sorry, they were 0 dp. Was just testing it out and posted it directly.But still doesn't work. I will edit it anyways

Comment: First of all, try to **flatten** your hierarchy. Not only it's hard to follow, but also bad for performances. Then `fill_parent` has been **deprecated** with Android 2.2. You should use `match_parent`. After all this, `weightSum` is **unnecessary**, because it's calculated automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When specifying weights in your layout, you must also set your height/width of your weighted view to **0dp**. One more thing, you need to set the **layout_height** of your linear layouts to **fill_parent**. You wrote it as **wrap_content**. That's why the weights were not clearly shown because there wasn't any view inside your linear layouts (*so their layout_height was like 0dp - they were hidden*).

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Header -->

    <include
        layout="@layout/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height" />

    <!-- Layout -->

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/light_blue"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/home_first_layout"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="10"
                android:baselineAligned="false">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <!-- <ImageView
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/upcoming" /> -->
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: posted the image in the question. There should be three different backgrounds in the first layout

Comment: works like a charm. Can you explain what was wrong previously

Comment: Added explanation in my answer. Please don't forget to vote my answer up as well if that worked for you. Thanks. :)